# Writing list of tuple to multiple CSV files [Python]

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, csv

Let's say I have a DataFrame like following.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['2019-10-01','2019-10-02','2019-10-03','2019-10-04'], 'B' : ['1.jpg','2.jpg','1.jpg', '2.jpg'], 'C': [5,8,9,4]})

    A             B     C
0   2019-10-01  1.jpg   5
1   2019-10-02  2.jpg   8
2   2019-10-03  1.jpg   9
3   2019-10-04  2.jpg   4
```

I want to select the rows which have the same name in Column B.  Then, write them to a CSV file having the number in column B. (For example, in the previous one I have to write to two CSV files such as '1.csv' and '2.csv').

```
1.csv

0   2019-10-01  1.jpg   5
2   2019-10-03  1.jpg   9
```

and

```
2.csv

1   2019-10-02  2.jpg   8
3   2019-10-04  2.jpg   4
```

The following code writes the output to a single file.

```
gb = df.groupby('B')    
gb2 = [gb.get_group(x) for x in gb.groups]

with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for item in gb2:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

How can I achieve my expected output?

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to post a question you should bring a minimum information as a input sample and expected output sample (if needed), what did you try and your research, in order to show some effort, as SO is not a free coding service. What did you try and research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['2019-10-01','2019-10-02','2019-10-03','2019-10-04'], 'B' : ['1.jpg','2.jpg','1.jpg', '2.jpg'], 'C': [5,8,9,4]})
gb = df.groupby('B')    
gb2 = [gb.get_group(x) for x in gb.groups]
for v in gb2:
    nm = v["B"].unique()[0]
    nm = nm.split(".")[0]
    v.to_csv(f"{nm}.csv")
```

Comment: Brilliant and Awsome! :) Thanks a lot. Works perfectly.

Comment: great,happy coding !!